# how to display the content of a structure in a listbox in a c# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, structure, windows-forms-designer

Dunno if I'm going the right way about this? The contents of the structure below is defined elsewhere. when I run the code it is just outputting a list of 4 zeros. any help would be greatly appreciated.....

```
public class NativeMethods
{

    public struct FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE
    {
        public uint ID;
        public uint LocId;       
        public string SerialNumber;           
        public string Description;
    }

    [DllImportAttribute(@"C:\Users\Brendan\Documents\libMPSSE.dll", EntryPoint = "SPI_GetNumChannels")]
    public static extern uint SPI_GetChannelInfo(uint index, ref FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE chanInfo);
}



public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<uint> items = new List<uint>();

    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        NativeMethods.FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE devlist = new NativeMethods.FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE();

        for(uint x=0;x<4;x++)
        {

        index = 0;
        items.Add(NativeMethods.SPI_GetChannelInfo(index, ref devlist));

         }
        listBox.DataSource = items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your extern function SPI_GetChannelInfo has DllImport attribute? Have you try to debug extern code (if you can)?

Comment: yes it imports a C DLL, I know it is working as 
I have output its contents to other textboxs. I cant seem to output all its parameters to a listbox though, maybe this is because they are different type parameters uint and string?

Comment: I left out the DLLimport attribute to make it more simple

Comment: maybe it makes more sense now

Comment: `List<uint>` is a list of numbers, so that's all you have.  What do you want to have in that ListBox?

Comment: I want to have each value in the structure displayed in the listbox 2 uints and 2 strings

Comment: Then clearly you can't use a `List<uint>`, as a string is not a uint.

Comment: I have tired to convert the uints to strings but not sure how to go about it, all I need to do is display them in the listbox. I'm new to programming

Comment: Is there a type instead of uint I can use, so I can output the two types? or can I convert the uints into strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wrote that your structure is defined elsewhere I asume you can't change it.

The usual way to get a custom made display string is to **wrap** your structure in a minimal class, maybe like this:

```
class FT_DEVICE_wrapper
{
    public FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE INFO_NODE { get; set; }

    public FT_DEVICE_wrapper(FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE data_)
    { INFO_NODE = data_; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("ID = {0} LocID = {1} SNr = {2} ({3}) ", 
          INFO_NODE.ID, INFO_NODE.LocId, INFO_NODE.SerialNumber, INFO_NODE.Description);
    }

}
```

Now you can add instances of the wrapper like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE N1 = new FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE();
    N1.ID = 1;
    N1.LocId = 1001;
    N1.SerialNumber = "123-456-00";
    N1.Description = "test 01";
    FT_DEVICE_wrapper W1 = new FT_DEVICE_wrapper(N1);

    listBox1.Items.Add(W1);

}
```

As you can see the structure's data are displayed in whichever way you format the output string.

And you can access the structure by casting the Items like this

```
Console.WriteLine( ((FT_DEVICE_wrapper) listBox1.Items[0]).INFO_NODE.Description );
```

Or, imo a little better like this:

```
FT_DEVICE_LIST_INFO_NODE node = ((FT_DEVICE_wrapper)listBox1.Items[0]).INFO_NODE;
Console.WriteLine(node.SerialNumber);
```

You **may** want to consider looking into `ListViews`, which support columns; here the way to add the structure would be quite different as you would want to put some of the date fields into separate columns.

If you want to use DataBinding you start by creating a proper List:

```
List<FT_DEVICE_wrapper> items = new List<FT_DEVICE_wrapper>();
```

and then replace

```
listBox1.Items.Add(W1);
```

by

```
items.Add(W1);
listBox1.DataSource = items;
```

Note: By simply adding a `ToString` method to the original structure you cold also make the structure display fine in the `ListBox` without being wrapped..

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was very helpful, I don't have enough rep to upvote you yet but I will when I get some.